# Null object reference error in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

im getting this error,it seems appears when i use findviewbyid from another class.

```
MainActivity:

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
          EditText usuario=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            usuario1  =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String user = usuario1.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            Esta asd=new Esta();
        asd.function();

        }
        });}
```

Esta.class:

```
package com.example.sori.facultad_if;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Esta extends AppCompatActivity{

    public void function() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        EditText thisone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

}}
```

Errors Log:

> 03-05 22:44:12.061  10088-10088/com.example.sori.facultad_if
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.sori.facultad_if, PID: 10088
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference

Thanks in advance

Comment: override android life cycle's method and write your code inside those methods in Esta class

Comment: what do you want to do, may be there was a better solution for your need, can you describe more about your 2 class?

Comment: @SagarChavada what do you mean with android life cicle's method?can you post an example with my code pls?Thanks

Comment: @Farrokh the problem is that i can't do nothing from Esta.class,i mean,i can't get the text of a EditText,can't set the text of a EditText,nothing.

Comment: i know this, but i want to know why you want to do this, your layout not inflated and thus there was no edittext, why do you need to set or get text in another class that not show and not active and etc, describe your main idea to find a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this :

MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText usuario=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Button boton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


                String user = usuario1.getText().toString();
                String pass = password.getText().toString();
                startActivity(new Intent(activity, ImageEditingActivity.class).putExtra("user", user).putExtra("pass", pass));

            }
        });

}
```

Esta.class:

```
package com.example.sori.facultad_if;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class Esta extends AppCompatActivity{

    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            //noinspection ConstantConditions
            String user = getIntent().getExtras().getString("user", "");
            String pass = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pass", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        EditText thisone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    }


}
```

Comment: I dont need get the user and password,i just want to edit the editText from Esta.class